# How to write into a definite table firestore on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

One user gives a book to another. I want to write books into a definite table 'Borrowed books'. How must I change the rules? For now I've got an exeption: W/Firestore(21240):[Firestore]: Write failed at Borrowed books/books: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

```
CollectionReference borrowedBooksTable =
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Borrowed books');

final borrowedBooksReference =
borrowedBooksTable.doc('books');
await borrowedBooksReference.set(borrowedBook.toJson());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [firestore: PERMISSION\_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590155/firestore-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions)

Comment: Of course, it does not

Answer (score 1):

By first enabling all reads and writes to that collection, you can examine how modifying security rules impacts this issue, as follows:

```
rules_version = '2'; service cloud.firestore { match /databases/{database}/documents { match /yourCollectionName/{ID}{ allow read, write: if true; } } }
```

and then limit the collection as necessary.

To make the necessary adjustments and implement best practices, consult [get started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) and [rules structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) recommendations.

Also, you can review the [answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61905641/16930243) for a similar question in Stackoverflow.

As a suggestion, take a look at this [link](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) explaining more about the issue.